# ROUTERS and SIP TELEPHONE

Tags: router, telephony

I have just installed a new router with enhanced firewall and wireless capabilities.  The new router does not have a DECT port, the unit from my ISP does, so I'm looking to interconnect the two to retain the use of the DECT port.

NewRouter is connected to the broadband network via the NBN NTU.  I have set a port forward for port 5060 (UDP/TCP) to OldRouter.  OldRouter is connected to NewRouter via LAN4 on NewRouter to WAN on OldRouter.  The DECT phone is connected to the DECT port on OldRouter.  OldRouter has a static IP assigned for the LAN port and is the same in PortForward.

OldRouter (I was hoping) would now connect to NewRouter and REGISTER the SIP service with the portforwarding doing the trick.  In NewRouter I have disabled SIP ALG in the firewall with no change.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: It's impossible to answer that without knowing what exactly goes wrong. So you need to debug the process of registering etc. from OldRouter. Put something between OldRouter and NewRouter that can record LAN packets, e.g. run `tcpdump` on NewRouter if you have root access and it runs an openfirmware, or connect up OldRouter temporarily to a PC, and use `wireshark` etc. One you *see* what packets OldRouter sense, you can investigate why they (or their answers) don't make it through NewRouter.

Comment: SIP might convey IP informations inside its data and sometime about other related flows. when doing the port forwarding, this might require alteration of the *data contents* of the packets. Eg, Linux ships with a [SIP NAT helper](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/netfilter/nf_nat_sip.c?h=v4.19.12) which is used along NAT (and the firewall) to handle this in kernel.